# Doctrine inverse side's collection field is randomly filled

Tags: symfony4

I have the following two entities address and user .
and in one of my controllers I have this function :

```
public function initAddressAction($idUser)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $address = new Address();

    /** @var User $user*/
    $user= $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User' )->find($idUser);
    if ($user!== null) {
        $address->setUser($user); 
            dump($user); // #1
            $addresses = $user->getAddresses()->toArray();
            dump($user);die; // #2
            ...}
```

My question is why the first dump prints the user object with an empty array in the addresses field :

`#collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#9487 ▼`

```
  -elements: []`
```

WHEREAS the second dump prints the  user object with a non empty array collection in the addresses field (there is actually one address in this array):

`#collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#9487 ▼`

```
  -elements: array:1 [▼

    0 => App\Entity\address{#81625 ▼`
```

User :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Address", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $addresses;

/**
 * Set addresses
 *
 * @param Collection $addresses
 */
public function setAddresses($addresses)
{
    $this->addresses= $addresses;
}

/**
 * Get addresses
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getAddresses()
{
    return $this->addresses;
}

/**
 * Add address
 *
 * @param Address $address
 * @return User
 */
public function addAddress(Address$address)
{
    if (!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
        $this->addresses[] = $address;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove address
 *
 * @param Address $address
 */
public function removeAddress(Address $address)
{
    $this->addresses->removeElement($address);
}
```

Address :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="adresses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user", nullable=false)
 */
private $user

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * @param User $user
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user= $user;
}
```

Comment: That's lazy loading: Doctrine does not load the objects in a collection until they are needed. The objects are loaded when a method on the collection is called. So, `dump($user)` dumps the user without the addresses, and after calling `getAddresses()->toArray()` the User's addresses are loaded from the database, added to the user and are visible in the second dump.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marleen , so now i can conclude that the array $adresses is filled without the need for calling addAddress method ? But suppose that  this line `$address->setUser($user);`  was not followed by `$addresses = $user->getAddresses`  then the array $addresses wouldn't be filled at all? In this case i would need to use AddAddress method?

Comment: That's right, the addresses property won't be filled in that case.

If later on in your code, you do use the addresses property (to print the addresses using a foreach, for example) the addresses will be loaded at that point in the code. And if you do not use the property later on in the code, the property will remain empty but the addresses are still in the database so they won't be lost.

Basically, you should use the User object as if it were completely loaded with its addresses and not worry about when and if the addresses are loaded.

Comment: The lazy loading only loads the addresses that are saved in the database. If you want to add a new address, that's not been saved to the database yet, to the user's addresses array, you do need to use addAddress().

Comment: Thank you so much @Marleen . and i would like to add that $addresses is not stored in db. So according to your answer , methods invoked here : https://coderedirect.com/questions/38646/understanding-of-owning-side-and-inverse-side-concepts-in-doctrine and here https://jeremymarc.github.io/2013/01/31/symfony-form-and-doctrine-inverse-side-association  can be used if I wanna add a new address , otherwise they could just call getCustomers() and the array would have been filled.

Comment: Only the addresses on the User's $addresses property get lazy loaded. To add a new address, add the User to the Address with `$address->setUser($user)`, this sets the owning side of the relationship. Then save the address with `persist($address)` and `flush()`. If you call `$addresses = $user->getAddresses()->toArray()` **after** the new address is saved, $addresses will then also contain the newly added address for the User.

Comment: (You could also call `$user->addAddress($address)` to add the new address, but inside the `addAddress()` method you would still need to do `$address->setUser($this)`, because you always need to set the owning side of the relationship.)

Comment: @Marleen thank you for you answers. But i have a question regarding https://coderedirect.com/questions/38646/understanding-of-owning-side-and-inverse-side-concepts-in-doctrine . In this example, customer is the owning side just like address in our case . The author said that `$customer->setCompany($company);` is not enough and we need to add `$company->setCustomer( $this );` in setcompany(). However in our case , we said that it is enough if we do `$address->setUser($user),` . both address and customer are owning sides ..so why is there a tiny difference between the article and our example?

Comment: Following your last comment I would say that the author must have written that `$company->setCustomer( $customer );` which resembles to `$user->addAddress($address)` in our case is the one that needs this    `$customer->setCompany($this)`  in the setCustomer function.

Comment: @Marleen could it be becausee the relationship in the article is OnetoOne?

Comment: This has to do with how you (want to) work with your objects in code versus the changes Doctrine requires to save the objects to the database correctly.

Comment: Doctrine only requires the owning side of the relationship to be set, so in the coderedirect example only the method `Customer::setCompany($company)` with `$this->company = $company;` is required.

Comment: If you also want to be able to set the Customer through the Company, you can also add `Company::setCustomer($customer)` with `$this->customer = $customer;`. Since Doctrine requires the owning side of the relationship to be set, the extra line `$customer->setCompany($this);` is needed.

Comment: `$company->setCustomer($this);` is then added to `Customer::setCompany($company)` to keep the object structure correct when working with the objects in code, this is not needed for Doctrine. It's a good practice to keep both sides of the relationship updated, but since the setters/adders are usually autogenerated by Symfony, this might be left out/forgotten if not needed/used.

Comment: Thank You again @Marleen ..So can you give an example in code that wouldn't have worked without having this part  `$company->setCustomer($this);`  aka `$user->addAddress($address)`   in `Customer::setCompany($company) `  aka `Address:setUser($user)` ? I just want to fully understand the part where you said that i might be useful when working with the objects in code (i got the part it is not required for Doctrine).

Comment: And one last question, last one :) so the last part on coderedirect is not correct right ? I mean this part : `And now imagine not having the line $company->setCustomer( $this ); in the setCompany method. If you then do $customer = $company->getCustomer(); after setting $company you will not get a Customer with id 1. `  ,

Comment: if fact, since  only the method `Customer::setCompany($company)` with `$this->company = $company;` is required then indeed after persisting and flushing, since the owning side is set , doctrine will save the relation on both sides and when you do `$company->getCustomer();`  , as we said in the first comments about `$addresses = $user->getAddresses()` , Doctrine will load the customer of the company and will add it to the company, so the customer whose ID is 1 will be visible in the result. This is why i think that was written in that article is not correct.

Comment: It depends on whether the references your object has to other objects/arrays-of-objects are already loaded from the database when you're doing the edit. In Symfony you can `dump()` the object and check the object's references to other objects/arrays-of-objects. If they're not loaded yet, they have an `initialized` or `__isInitialized__` property that is set to false (Doctrine replaces the references with fake objects/arrays until the real objects are needed).

Comment: If you then edit the other side of such a reference, save to the database, and then try and access the reference on the first object, the reference will be loaded from the database so it will have new object.

Comment: But if your object's references are already loaded, or you are not saving to the database inbetween (which is usually the case!) then the example on coderedirect is correct and you will not get the new object. If you write your objects so that both sides of the relation get updated at all times then this Doctrine lazy-loading is not something you have to worry about. :)

Comment: Thank You again @Marleen !! Could you please lastly give me examples related to my case or the coderedirect case to understand you last comments `if you then edit the other side of such a reference, save to the database,`  ,   `But if your object's references are already loaded, or you are not saving to the database inbetween (which is usually the case!)` ,  `..are already loaded from the database when you're doing the edit. ` , can you tell me which lines are you talking about in my code or the coderedirect example so that i can follow you just like you explained to me at first  ?

Comment: Added as an answer as it got too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generated a User and an Address class via the Symfony maker bundle.

User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, mappedBy="userField")
     */
    private $addresses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Address>
     */
    public function getAddresses(): Collection
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }

    public function addAddress(Address $address): self
    {
        if (!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
            $this->addresses[] = $address;
            $address->setUserField($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAddress(Address $address): self
    {
        if ($this->addresses->removeElement($address)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($address->getUserField() === $this) {
                $address->setUserField(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Address:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AddressRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AddressRepository::class)
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $userField;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUserField(): ?User
    {
        return $this->userField;
    }

    public function setUserField(?User $userField): self
    {
        $this->userField = $userField;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Example that fails:**

Try this (in a controller for example):

```
    // get address 1 (this is attached to user 1 in the database)
    $address1 = $addressRepo->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
    dump($address1);
```

[image]

This is Address 1, its User object has not been initalized yet, but that's not important for this example.

```
    // get user 2 (user 2 only has address 2 in the database)
    $user2 = $userRepo->findOneBy(['id' => 2]);
    dump($user2);
```

[image]

This is User 2, notice that the Address array is not initialized yet (this is important!).

```
    // set user 2 onto address 1
    $address1->setUserField($user2);
    dump($address1);
```

[image]

Now Address 1 has User 2.

```
    dump($user2);
```

[image]

But User 2 does not have Address 1.

```
    // load user 2's addresses from the database
    $user2->getAddresses()->toArray();
    dump($user2);
```

[image]

User 2 now has it's Address 2 loaded from the database (still no Address 1 though).

**With $userField->addAddress($this)**

If you add the `$userField->addAddress($this);` line:

```
public function setUserField(?User $userField): self
{
    $this->userField = $userField;
    $userField->addAddress($this);

    return $this;
}
```

And execute the same steps:

```
    // get address 1 (this is attached to user 1 in the database)
    $address1 = $addressRepo->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
    dump($address1);

    // get user 2  (user 2 only has address 2 in the database)
    $user2 = $userRepo->findOneBy(['id' => 2]);
    dump($user2);

    // set user 2 onto address 1
    $address1->setUserField($user2);
    dump($address1);
    dump($user2);
```

[image]

User 2 now does have Address 1. Adding the Address to the User also triggers the loading of the existing Adresses from the database, so it now also has Address 2.

```
    // load user 2's addresses from the database
    $user2->getAddresses()->toArray();
    dump($user2);
```

[image]

(The Addresses were already loaded, no changes.)

**With persist & flush**

And if you **do not** add the `$userField->addAddress($this);` line, but add persist & flush:

```
    // get address 1 (this is attached to user 1 in the database)
    $address1 = $addressRepo->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
    dump($address1);

    // get user 2  (user 2 only has address 2 in the database)
    $user2 = $userRepo->findOneBy(['id' => 2]);
    dump($user2);

    // set user 2 onto address 1
    $address1->setUserField($user2);
    dump($address1);
    dump($user2);
```

[image]

User 2 does not have Address 1.

```
    // persist address 1
    $em->persist($address1);
    $em->flush($address1);

    // load user 2's addresses from the database
    $user2->getAddresses()->toArray();
    dump($user2);
```

[image]

Now User 2 has both Address 1 and Address 2 loaded from the database.

Comment: couldn't thank you enough for this clear explanation ! Thanks @Marleen ! effectively everything you wrote is correct !

Comment: Just to end it up @Marleen , so in coderedirect phrase `And now imagine not having the line $company->setCustomer( $this ); in the setCompany method.  If you then do $customer = $company->getCustomer(); after setting $company you will not get a Customer with id 1` , he means that he's doing the dump() after this line `$customer->setCompany($company);` in his code right ? because if he had done a dump() after the flush, as he's calling `$company->getCustomer()` then he would have obtained the customer with id 1 even without putting `$company->setCustomer( $this )` in setCompany method.

Comment: He is assuming both the Customer and the Company objects are already fully loaded.
If you then call the `setCompany` method without the `$company->setCustomer($this)` line, and then do `$customer = $company->getCustomer()` then you would also get the "old" Customer.

Comment: But if the Company's Customer is not yet loaded from the database, and you call the `setCompany` method without the `$company->setCustomer($this)` line, then persist & flush, and then call `$customer = $company->getCustomer()` then you would indeed get the "new" Customer from the database.

Comment: ah i see @Marleen so it's a bit different case than your last screenshot :-) Thanks again :) and now we're done with this issue :D

Comment: When talking about object oriented design, you always assume that all object references exist, as if there was no database. With a database the case could be the same as in my last example, or with all or some of the references already loaded.